# laravel asset file not lodded after copy .htaccess and index.php from public to root directory

Tags: php, laravel, css

here is my source code look like this.i am new in laravel ,please my solve the problem

```
<link href="http://localhost/eccomece/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to update the asset() method also  ... 
Go to this directory 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\detox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helper.php`

and update the asset()function like bellow:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='127.0.0.1:8000')
            return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost:8000')
            return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
        else
            return app('url')->asset('public/'.$path, $secure);
    }
```